# Как управлять адаптивностью на самой странице без перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript, html, css, расширения

Есть расширение для Мозиллы и Хрома
Есть 2 файла `CSS`, назовем их `style1.css` и `style2.css`
`style1.css` - стили для ПК версии
`style2.css` - стили для mobile friendly
Как сделать так, чтобы можно было управлять тем, какой стиль использовать?

Пример.
Страница `popup.html`
имеет 2 кнопки:
1 кнопка - нажатие данной кнопки запускает `style1.css` и получается версия страницы для ПК **без перезагрузки**.
2 кнопка - нажатие данной кнопки запускает `style2.css` и получается версия страницы для mobile **без перезагрузки**.
Важно чтобы перезагрузки не происходило. Как это возможно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно пробовать так)

```js
(function(){

var styles = [
  "style-1.css",
  "style-2.css",
  "style-3.css",
  "style-4.css",
];

var style = document.getElementById('style-link');
var toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-style');
for( var i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++ ){
  toggleStyle(i);
}

function toggleStyle(i){
  toggle[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    style.href = styles[i];
  });
}

})();
```

```html
<link id="style-link" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-1.css" >

Откуда Вы?<br>
<button class="toggle-style">ПК</button>
<button class="toggle-style">Мобильный</button>
<button class="toggle-style">Калькулятор</button>
<button class="toggle-style">Стиральная Машинка</button>
```

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

1) Создаёте две кнопки в HTML, каждая из которых выволняете JS-функцию подстановки пути к нужному файлу стилей

```
<button onclick="toDesktop()">To Desktop</button>
<button onclick="toMobile()">To Mobile</button>
```

2) В `<head>` задаёте тегу `<link>`, через который подключаете стили, `id`

```
<link id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
```

3)Через JS меняете тегу `<link>` значение атрибута `href`

```
function toMobile() {
    document.getElementById("stylesheet").href = "style1.css";
}

function toDesktop() {
    document.getElementById("stylesheet").href = "style2.css";
}
```

Comment: Сразу два подключать в хид можно стиля они не будут перебивать друг друга и какая версия стиля при этом вначале будет работать?

Comment: @Arcadiy, сразу два стиля можно подключать, но в приведенном примере подключается только один. При нажатии на кнопку меняется на другой, так что перебивать никто никого не будет

Comment: Нажатие кнопок к сожалению ник чему не приводит

Comment: Вот архив с примером: https://fex.net/s/mxsetl7

Comment: Проблема в том, что если это делать для расширения chrome или для дополнения Mozilla это не работает

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Comment: Расширение выдает при нажатии кнопки вот такое сообщение --- 
popup.html:24 Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: И такое  --- Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-V+iNl6QmON72aRSKS2oTemXSXqRfVEpORGTUxzjG+Js='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Прошу прощения, что сразу не написал что это расширение